# Cocoa Pods removed during update

Tags: cocoapods

I updated cocoa pods on my machine since my information was not displaying in my beta app. After the pods updated a firebase and protobuf pod were removed. Has anyone ever had this happen?

Comment: Which command have you used to update Cocoapods?

Comment: pod update, in the file

Comment: if your app works normal than this is expected

Comment: my app is missing color in parts and no information is being sent to the app in my phone

Comment: It is really hard to help you because you haven't provide a lot information. The first solution that I can think of is to add this pods back to podfile and install them.

Comment: What more info would you need?I have uninstalled and reinstalled the cocoa pods and updated them.....I was told I need to possibly update my code as well??